# Add comma separator for text with currency(USD) using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following example I want to make 16000.00 USD to **16,000.00 USD** but I tried with toLocalString to add comma separator and bind the **USD** at last. But I couldn't make it.

Anyone help me to achieve this.

Actual Result: `16,000.00`

Expected Result: `16,000.00 USD`

```js
var price = $("abbr").text()
var abbr_text = parseFloat(price)
result_ainp = abbr_text.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2})
console.log('result_ainp',result_ainp)
$("abbr").text(result_ainp)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<abbr>16000 USD</abbr>
```

Comment: Instead of calling `parseFloat` immediately, just split the text using space with `.split(' ')`, then parse the float, process it, and put it back with the other piece of the split.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I tried with .split method. but no luck. If possible to provide snippet from your side

Comment: `new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD', currencyDisplay: 'code' }).format(16000)` (note the "USD" would be in front in "en-US" convention, so i took some convention where it isn't, here "de-DE". You should probably choose the one your product is aimed at).

Comment: @ASDFGerte USD is a dynamic. Sometimes it will be CAN currency also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by splitting the string first, using [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), processing the number on its own, then putting the string back before assigning it to the element.

*Note*: the snippet below contains more things defined than it should be, but it's on purpose to showcase the result of each step.

*Note*: the snippet below also makes use of [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
const price = $("abbr").text();
const [amount, currency] = price.split(' ');
const parsedAmount = parseFloat(amount);
const processedAmount = parsedAmount.toLocaleString(
    undefined,
    { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }
);
const finalPrice = `${processedAmount} ${currency}`;
$("abbr").text(finalPrice);
console.log('result_ainp', finalPrice);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<abbr>16000 USD</abbr>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful:

JavaScript's `Intl.NumberFormat()` enables language-sensitive number formatting without the need for a third-party library.

Comprehensive docs on MDN for it: [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat)

Example:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: "currency", currency: "USD"}).format(123456.789) // '$123,456.79'

new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: "currency", currency: "EUR"}).format(123456.789) // '123.456,79 €'
```